# Separating two/tree divs in one div?

Tags: html, css

I need some help on how I can write some HTML code. Currently I'm having one html file, call it "main.html" with a div where I upload stuff from another html-file (in this case"faq_contact.html").

How can I structure the HTML to get a similar structure to the one Nespresso has on this page: [image]

I want the top box with "Contact Nespresso" and the two ones below it.
I tried going through their code with "inspect page source" but could find anything.

Comment: I've tried looking at other similar questions but their solutions didn't work for my problem somehow.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far. It will be easy for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width in `%` to both the divs such that the sum is less than 100. `float` one div to the left and the other to the right.

```css
#heading {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#main-div {
  background-color: #eee;
  float:left;
}

#side-div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  float:right;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-75 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-20 {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="heading">HEADING</div>
<br>
<div class="col-75" id="main-div">Main Div</div>
<div class="col-20" id="side-div">Side Div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a `div` and includes 3 `div`s inside the outer div. Then I assigned 100% height to first inner `div` and 50% height to the other two inner `div`s (you can adjust as you want). Then I set the first `div` with `display: inline` and `width: 70%` and also, I floated the `div` to the left and I set the other two `div`s with `display: inline-block` and I set the width of the other two `div`s such that they seem to appear adjacent to first `div`. Please see the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
     .example {
    width: 100%;
     }
    .span-full-height {
     display: inline;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
        border-right: 0.5px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .span-half-height {
     display: inline-block;
        height: 50%;
        width: 25%;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
        padding: 3px;
    }
    .span-half-height-2 {
     display: inline-block;
        height: 50%;
        width: 25%;
        padding: 3px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="example">
 <div class="span-full-height">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span-half-height">
     <p>Hello World</p>
        <p>How are you?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span-half-height-2">
     <p>Contact: 00000000</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your content is in separate files you could use iframes like:

```
<div>
    <h1>Contact Nespresso</h1>
</div>
<iframe src="~/leftcontent.html" style="float:left; width:75%"></iframe>
<iframe src="~/rightcontent.html" style="float:right; width:25%"></iframe>
```

If you're generating the content and are happy using Twitter bootstrap you could do:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>Contact Nespresso</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">left content</div>
<div class="col-md-4">right content</div>
```

In both cases you'll need to add some styling & shouldn't really use inline css, using it here as an example.

If you wanted to go old school, you could use a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <h1>Contact Nespresso</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 75%;">left content</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;">right content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But this, really isnt the recommended way of doing this as its not responsive.